# Loss of double precision C#

Tags: c#, casting, floating-point, double, naudio

I am experiencing precision loss when im using doubles and i cant seem to find where the precision is lost.
I am writing a software synthesizer and for some reason the input frequency for an oscillator(sound-wave generator) gets heavily aliased somewhere along the way.
The oscillator is supposed to generate a triangle waveform and the correct frequency is passed to the method but when the result is played in the speakers i can clearly hear that the sound snaps to different frequencies.

I am using NAudio (http://naudio.codeplex.com/) and this method is run once for every sample i want to generate.

Here is the code:

```
double counter = 0;
int samplecounter = 0;

public double GetNextTriangle(double frequency)
{
    double samplesperwave = (double)Parent.WaveFormat.SampleRate / frequency;
    double length = (double)samplecounter / samplesperwave;
    if (length.CompareTo(0.25) == -1)
    {
        counter = length * 4.0;
    }
    else if (length.CompareTo(0.75) == -1)
    {
        counter = 1.0 - (length - 0.25) * 4.0;
    }
    else
    {
        counter = -1.0 + (length - 0.75) * 4.0;
    }
    samplecounter++;
    samplecounter = samplecounter > samplesperwave ? 0 : samplecounter;
    return counter;
}
```

Thanks in advance! //Mats

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to step through your code?

Comment: Please use `<` and `>` operators rather than `CompareTo`!!

Comment: Feed in 1000 equally spaced values in the desired frequency range. See if the output is continuous. I expect it won't be. If you discover that it is not, then it's your job to work out why not.

Comment: @Dai So that the code may be readily understood by humans.

Comment: I have tried stepping through the code but it's still pretty hard to find where the precision is lost.
I used the "CompareTo" method just to see if it made any difference.

Comment: Also, why is `counter` a field rather than a local variable?

Comment: @DOOMDUDEMX anyway, if you must use CompareTo, you should use `if (a.CompareTo(b) < 0)` not `if (a.CompareTo(b) == -1)`, because the method's contract allows it to return any value less than zero if the receiver is less than the argument.

Comment: @DOOMDUDEMX If you can't debug this by reading the code, then you simply need to plot the output and compare it to what you are expecting. The issue is not precision. For sure. The issue is that you've not coded the equations correctly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan 
I have made several methods similar to this one where there was a need for it and copied the code.
I didn't think of changing the code when that need no longer existed.
I will try your suggestion though.

Comment: @DOOMDUDEMX you're best off finding specific values for which you get unexpected results.  Then step through the method to find the first calculation that yields an unexpected value.  Then add to your answer the values of the input variables, the result of the calculation, and the result you expected.

Comment: In addition to the several excellent answers already provided below, it is worth considering using a WaveTable for a software synthesizer. With this approach you pre-calculate your waveform, and then index into it (optionally interpolating between entries in the table if you need to support changing frequency or portamento)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The floating point operations here are well conditionned. But you may see an alisaing problem related to sampling if 1/frequency is not a multiple of 1/sampleRate.

Try this matlab code if you can

```
sampleRate=5000;
frequency=700;
sampleperwave=sampleRate/frequency;
samplecounter=0:floor(sampleperwave);
samplecounter=repmat(samplecounter,1,5);
length=samplecounter/sampleperwave;
wave=-1+4*(length-0.75);
wave(length<0.75)=1-4*(length(length<0.75)-0.25);
wave(length<0.25)=4*length(length<0.25);
figure; stem(wave); hold on; plot(wave,'r')
```

[image: discontinuity]

You could try to declare samplecounter as double and increment it with a modulo

```
samplecounter++;
samplecounter = samplecounter % samplesperwave;
```

Or back in matlab

```
samplecounter=0:length(samplecounter)-1;
samplecounter=rem(samplecounter,sampleperwave);
len=samplecounter/sampleperwave;
wave=-1+4*(len-0.75);
wave(len<0.75)=1-4*(len(len<0.75)-0.25);
wave(len<0.25)=4*len(len<0.25);
figure; stem(wave); hold on; plot(wave,'r')
```

[image: aliasing]

Comment: Changing the SampleCounter to double worked perfectly!
I did plot out the values in realtime using the values for the position of a TrackBar-Control but this slight inconsistency was hard to spot using my method.
This was very well explained!
Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not one of precision. The issue is that your function does not define a triangle wave. Each time `samplecounter` is reset to 0, the next returned value from the function is 0. Next time round length is set to 0, the first if branch is executed and counter is set to 0.

When faced with a problem like this you should plot the output. Had you done so you would have seen immediately that your function does not produce a triangle wave form.  Here's some code that does:

```
static double GetNextTriangle(double frequency)
{
    double samplesperwave = Parent.WaveFormat.SampleRate / frequency;
    double t = samplecounter / samplesperwave;
    counter = 1.0 - 4.0 * Math.Abs(Math.Round(t - 0.25) - (t - 0.25));
    samplecounter++;
    return counter;
}
```

Again, I cannot stress enough that you must plot and visualize the output from your code to gain insight into its behaviour.

Comment: The function is generating samples which together makes a soundwave.
When the wave has done one loop i set the counter back to 0 so the process can start over.
The method is supposed to return a value between -1 and 1.
If i dont set the counter to 0 the resulting value will continue to grow out of bounds.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. The discontinuity is the reason for your messy sound.

Comment: +1, You'll have a sampling problem with potential aliasing when wave period (1/frequency) is not a multiple of sample period. For example, take frequency=700Hz and sampleRate=5kHz. By resetting samplecounter to zero, you transform the aliasing problem into a discontinuity problem at each period (with sampling, it will stop before reaching final zero). Represent samplecounter as double and use a modulo(samplecounter+1,sampleperwave).

Comment: @aka Is that comment addressed at me? There's no aliasing with the code in my answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sorry for confusion, I mean DOOMDUDEMX has a sampling problem, and +1 to you for exposing the discontinuity related to this aliasing problem

Answer (score 2):

To try and get a better idea of what's wrong, let's visualize the data. Here's two cycles of a 2 Hz wave at 41 samples per second:

[image]

There's a blip around sample 20. It looks like the samples aren't fitting a triangle wave properly.

Let's go over the math of a triangle wave. What you're doing is sampling a continuous function at discrete points. First, define a continuous triangle wave of frequency `f` (or `1/T`) in hertz:

```
tri(t) =   {  4*f*t,            0     <= t < T/4   }
       =   { -4*f*(t - T/2),    T/4   <= t < 3*T/4 }
       =   {  4*f*(t - T),      3*T/4 <= t < T     }
       =   tri(t - T)  [it's periodic!]
```

You now want to sample this continuous function. So you define a sampling rate, `s` (or `1/U`) in samples per second. Now, the `n`th sample will simply be `tri(n*U)`:

```
tri[n] = tri(n*U)
       =   {  4*f*n*U,            0     <= n*U < T/4   }
       =   { -4*f*(n*U - T/2),    T/4   <= n*U < 3*T/4 }
       =   {  4*f*(n*U - T),      3*T/4 <= n*U < T     }
```

Let's clean it up a bit by defining the normalized period, `P = T/U`, and the normalized frequency, `F = f/s = U/T`:

```
tri[n] =   {  4*F*n,            0     <= n < P/4   }
       =   { -4*F*(n - P/2),    P/4   <= n < 3*P/4 }
       =   {  4*F*(n - P),      3*P/4 <= n < P     }
```

Now we get this:

[image]

Don't worry about the apparent "blips" at the tips; they are to be expected and you shouldn't try to avoid them.

Here's the code:

```csharp
public static double GetNextTriangle(int sample, double frequency, double sampleRate)
{
    double T = 1d / frequency;
    double U = 1d / sampleRate;

    double P = T / U;
    double F = U / T;

    double n = (double)sample;
    n %= P; // restrict n to the domain [0, P)

    if ((n >= 0) && (n < (P / 4d)))
    {
        return 4d * F * n;
    }
    else if ((n >= (P / 4d)) && (n < (3d * P / 4d)))
    {
        return -4d * F * (n - (P / 2d));
    }
    else // if ((n >= (3d * P / 4d)) && (n < P))
    {
        return 4d * F * (n - P);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole approach seems wrong. I'd go with something like this:

```
public class RectWave
{ // triangular wave in range [0,1] with given frequency
    public double GetNextSample()
    {
        if (_ptr == _wave.Length)
            _ptr = 0;
        return _wave[_ptr++];
    }

    public RectWave(int sampleRate = 441000, int period = 20)
    { 
        _sampleRate = sampleRate;
        _period = period;
        _wave = new double[(int)(_sampleRate * _period / 1000.0)];  // one cycle
        _ptr = 0;
        BuildWave();
    }

    private void BuildWave()
    {
        double dt = 1000.0 / _sampleRate;   // in msec
        double slope = 1.0 / (_period / 2.0);   // 1.0 => peek 
        for (int i=0; i <= _wave.Length/2; ++i)
        {
            _wave[i] = _wave[_wave.Length - i - 1] = i * dt * slope; 
        }
    }

    private int _sampleRate;    // in Hz
    private int _period;        // in msec
    private double[] _wave;     // the data
    private int _ptr;           // current sample
}
```